# How to open a virtual environment created with pyenv with VSCode editor?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, pyenv

I am working on a Linux environment and have created my virtual environment using the `pyenv` tool. I have set the local virtual environment in my working folder the the one I want with `pyenv` from command line like this for example : `pyenv local my_venv_name` which in my case `my_venv_name=3.9.9`

When I opened VSCode in that folder the integrated terminal is indeed opening that virtual environment BUT the code in the VSCode seems to not be able to find some installed dependencies that I can see that I have installed in that particular environment. I can do `pip freeze` in the terminal and I see the packages but VSCode does not see them.

How can I set the correct virtual environment to the VSCode editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so you have to select the correct python interpreter because `pyenv` could be using multiple python version in different environments. I found two ways to change it:

1. Open the `command palette` either from the gear icon bottom left corner or by typing `Ctrl + Shift + P`. Then type `select python interpreter` and select the one that corresponds to the virtual environment you want
2. You can find the same option by simply clicking and selecting the interpreter from the bottom right corner of the VSCode as shown in the image below:

[image]